# Cannot connect to OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I created a VPN server using the openvpn platform. I can connect successfully through my android phone but not through my laptop, both ubuntu and windows OS.

When I run the following command:

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

I get the following error:

```
Mon Oct 28 17:45:43 2019 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
Mon Oct 28 17:45:43 2019 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Mon Oct 28 17:45:43 2019 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Mon Oct 28 17:45:43 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]3.9.169.100:1194
Mon Oct 28 17:45:43 2019 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Mon Oct 28 17:45:43 2019 UDP link local: (not bound)
Mon Oct 28 17:45:43 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]3.9.169.100:1194
Mon Oct 28 17:45:44 2019 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]3.9.169.100:1194, sid=9171bd9d a2c42c74
Mon Oct 28 17:45:44 2019 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Mon Oct 28 17:45:44 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=OpenVPN CA
Mon Oct 28 17:45:44 2019 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Mon Oct 28 17:45:44 2019 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=OpenVPN Server
Mon Oct 28 17:45:45 2019 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Mon Oct 28 17:45:45 2019 [OpenVPN Server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]3.9.169.100:1194
Mon Oct 28 17:45:46 2019 SENT CONTROL [OpenVPN Server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,explicit-exit-notify,topology subnet,route-delay 5 30,dhcp-pre-release,dhcp-renew,dhcp-release,route-metric 101,ping 12,ping-restart 50,compress stub-v2,redirect-gateway def1,redirect-gateway bypass-dhcp,redirect-gateway autolocal,route-gateway 172.27.232.1,dhcp-option DNS 172.31.0.2,register-dns,block-ipv6,ifconfig 172.27.232.19 255.255.248.0,peer-id 1,auth-tokenSESS_ID,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 Option 'explicit-exit-notify' in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:1 is ignored by previous <connection> blocks 
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: dhcp-pre-release (2.4.4)
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: dhcp-renew (2.4.4)
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:6: dhcp-release (2.4.4)
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:16: register-dns (2.4.4)
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:17: block-ipv6 (2.4.4)
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: explicit notify parm(s) modified
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: compression parms modified
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1625
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.43.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlp4s0 HWADDR=48:5a:b6:dc:26:a7
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Mon Oct 28 17:45:47 2019 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 172.27.232.19/21 broadcast 172.27.239.255
Mon Oct 28 17:45:52 2019 ROUTE remote_host is NOT LOCAL
Mon Oct 28 17:45:52 2019 /sbin/ip route add 3.9.169.100/32 via 192.168.43.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mon Oct 28 17:45:52 2019 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Mon Oct 28 17:45:52 2019 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 172.27.232.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mon Oct 28 17:45:52 2019 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Mon Oct 28 17:45:52 2019 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 172.27.232.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Mon Oct 28 17:45:52 2019 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Mon Oct 28 17:45:52 2019 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

Can anyone explain to me what the problem is? I have tried to connect to it through different wireless networks but the same problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Could you specify the versions you use?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your client and server ovpn config files, otherwise problem is impossible to diagnose.

Comment: OpenVPN was installed using the script provided by angristan on Github: https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install , i tested on other peoples devices, its working, so the problem is with my device, any idea what could it be ? Also the ISP could be blocking me since VPN are illegal on the country I'm currently on... ops.